# How to capture a streaming video using WebRTC

Tags: streaming, webrtc, video-capture

the following code is similar to the one written in Mozilla Developer's Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos.

For some reasons,the webcam is not turned on when ran under a server.ejs. Only a button a shown. I suspect some editorial exists on the code, it would be nice if we could find where the problem stands? Thank you

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head> 
 <title> Introduction to WebRTC </title>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 </head>
 <body> 

 <p> <button id = "takeProfilePicture" type="button" autofocus="true">Create Profile Picture</button></p>
 <video autoplay></video>
 <video id="videoTag" autoplay></video>
 <canvas id = "profilePicCanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
 <div>
 <img id = "profilePictureOutput">
 </div>

<script> 
 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia  ||         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

 var constraints = {
  audio: false, 
  video: {
           mandatory: {

             minWidth  : 240,
             maxWidth  : 240,
             minHeight : 240,
             maxHeight : 240
             }
             }
           };

 var videoArea = document.querySelector("video");
 var profilePicCanvas = document.querySelector("#profilePicCanvas");
 var profilePictureOutput =   document.querySelector("#profilePictureOutput");
var takePicButton = document.querySelector("#takeProfilePicture");
var videoTag = document.querySelector("#videoTag");

var width  = 240 ;
var height = 0   ;
var streaming = false ;

takePicButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
takeProfilePic();
ev.PreventDefault();
}, false;) 

videoTag.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
if (!streaming) {
height = videoTag.videoHeight / (videoTag.videoWidth/width);

if (isNaN(height)) {

height = width / (4/3) ;

}
videoTag.setAttribute('width',width);
videoTag.setAttribute('height',height);
profilePicCanvas.setAttribute('width',width);
profilePicCanvas.setAttribute('height',height);
streaming = true ;


}
},false);

function takeProfilePic() {
var context = profilePicCanvas.getContext('2d');
if (width && height) {
 profilePicCanvas.width  = width ;
 profilePicCanvas.height = height ;

 context.drawImage(videoTag, 0 , 0 , width, height);

 var data = profilePicCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
 profilePictureOutput.setAttribute('src',data);
 }
 }

navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess(stream) {
console.log("Sucess! We have a stream!");
videoArea.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
videoArea.className = "grayscale_filter";
videoArea.play() ;

}

function onError(error) {

console.log("Error with getUserMedia: ", error);
}

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you got two mistakes in your code `}, false;)` must be changed to `}, false);` and `ev.PreventDefault();` must be changed to `ev.preventDefault();`...

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I modified these typos after I sent the message. The problem remains the same. 

What I noticed is that "height = 0"  and takeProfilePic() method seems not to be invoked. I have not been able to figure out the problem yet ?!

Comment: other than the problems I mentioned in comments, I am not sure why you have two `video` tags, that is causing the issue... once I merged them, things became fine, [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x1v2nrox/)

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. my mistake !